# How do you enable auto clean up of anonymous users in Googles Identity Platform?

Tags: firebase, google-identity

I have a Firebase project that I have upgraded to the Google Cloud Identity Platform and have added the anonymous sign in feature. Google offers an auto clean up feature that has to be enabled. It's not active by default, but for the life of me I cannot see anywhere in the Google Cloud Platform where to enable this and they do not give specifics on how to enable it in the docs here.... https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#auto-cleanup

How is this enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform option, you can <kbd>Enable anonymous account clean-up</kbd> in the last step of the upgrade wizard here:

[image]

This option only shows up after you've [enabled the Anonymous account provider](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers) in the Firebase console.

After the upgrade, you can change the <kbd>Enable Auto clean-up</kbd> setting in the [anonymous account provider settings page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers):

[image]

I'm not sure if the setting is available in the Cloud console outside of the Firebase console, but I can't find it there at least.

Comment: I knew it would be hiding in plain sight! Your solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I'd never tried it, so this was a good reason to investigate. 

Comment: I started this project in 2018 before the new authentication system, and I must say the transition to the new Identify Platform has been seamless and very easy. The auto clean up was the only part I missed during the set up wizard, so all that aside a great upgrade experience!